# normalizer tower question

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

Let $P$ be a finite $p$-group and $Q$ a proper subgroup of $P$. Define the normalizer tower of $Q$ in $P$ as follow:

\begin{equation} N^0(Q) = Q \mbox{ and } N^i(Q) = N_P(N^{i-1}(Q)) \end{equation}
for $1 \leq i \leq m$, where $m$ is the smallest positive integer satisfying $N^m(Q) = P$.

We say that $Q$ has maximal normalizer tower in $P$ if $[P : Q] = p^m$ (i.e.  $[N^i : N^{i-1}] = p$ for all $1 \leq i \leq m$).

Denote the Frattini subgroup of a group $G$ by $\Phi(G)$.

I want to show that if $\Phi(N^i) \leq N^{i-2}$, then $N^{i-2} \vartriangleleft N^i$.

I try to show that $N^{i-2}$ is a maximal subgroup of $N^i$ in this case (since $N^i$ is nilpotent, every maximal subgroup is normal and we are done).
But $N^{i-2} \lneq N^{i-1} \lneq N^i$, so it doesn't seem like a good idea...

What can I do? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you defining maximal normaliser tower and then never using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a $p$-group, the quotient by the Frattini subgroup is elementary abelian. It follows that every subgroup containing the Frattini is normal. What you want immediately follows. As you pointed out, this eventually leads to a contradiction.